# Array type hints conflict between Drupal and Symfony

Tags: 9, coding-standards

In an event subscriber, I have:

```
  /**
   * Registers the methods in this class that should be listeners.
   *
   * @return array
   *   An array of event listener definitions.
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
    return [KernelEvents::TERMINATE => [['onTerminate', 100]]];
  }
```

However, when I check this with PHPStan, I get an error:

> Return type (array) of method
> Drupal\MyModule\EventSubscriber\AnalyticsEventSubscriber::getSubscribedEvents()
> should be covariant with return type (array<string, mixed>) of method
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface::getSubscribedEvents()

Symfony 4 EventSubscriberInterface:

```
/**
 * @return array<string, mixed> The event names to listen to
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents();
```

So I changed my comment to:

```
   * @return array<string, mixed>
```

But when I check against Drupal coding standards:

> ERROR | Return type "array<string, mixed>" must not contain spaces

So I try taking out the space:

```
   * @return array<string,mixed>
```

Now checking against Drupal coding standards gives a different error:

> ERROR | [x] Expected "arraystringmixed" but found "array<string,mixed>" for function return type

Obviously I could just disable the PHPStan check, but is there a way to use Symfony's array type hints in Drupal in a way that the Drupal coding standards understand?